# Best Practice: Passing a Vector of a Derived Class to a Method on a Vector of a Base Class

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, std, stdvector

This is a "best practice" question: I can think of several ways to do it, but I would like to know which one the community thinks is the best.

I have a method as follows:

```
void Foo(std::vector<BaseClass>& Objects) {...}
```

I now want to call this method on an `Objects` which is an `std::vector<DerivedClass>`.

I can think, e.g., of using a template, or converting Sort to take `std::vector<BaseClass*>` and then passing `(Objects.begin(), Objects.end())`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there some reason you want to use your own sort function, instead of using `std::sort`?

Comment: Yes (I can explain if you like). But it's only a coincidence that it happens to be a Sorting function - in general it could be anything. I've changed the name in the question to avoid confusion - thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: In that case, "best practice" would be to follow the pattern people would expect.  The standard library uses template-functions with iterator inputs, and I would highly suggest you do the same (it would make your life much easier).

Comment: @mga in case you are unaware of it: be careful that you **cannot** store a `DerivedClass` inside a `std::vector<BaseClass>`, this would be the typical example of object slicing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice would be to accept a pair of iterators delineating the range of elements upon which Foo should operate, possibly providing convenience functions to convert ranges to iterators:

```
template <typename Iter>
void Foo(Iter first, Iter last) {...}
void Foo(std::vector<BaseClass>& Objects) {
  Foo(begin(Objects), end(Objects));
}
void Foo(std::vector<DerivedClass>& Objects) {
  Foo(begin(Objects), end(Objects));
}

// Or even a generic range adaptor,
template <typename Range>
void Foo(Range&& r) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  Foo(begin(r), end(r));
}
```

Comment: I would avoid the convenience functions and just provide the template with iterator inputs (and possible a predicate).  That way it is consistent with the standard library and would be what people would expect.

Comment: This seems to be the best way. Small question: if I have in Class.h: template<typename Iter> void Foo(Iter first, Iter last); how should I write the implementation in Class.cpp? If I do template<typename Iter> void Classname::Foo(Iter first, Iter last) {...} I'm getting an error. I have to admit I'm a little out of my depth here.

Answer (score 3):

If you need dynamic polymorphism you may consider std::shared_ptr, std::unique_ptr  or a class containing a pointer to a (internal) polymorph class. In other words 'std::vector< BaseClass* >' is plain ugly.

If you use static polymorphism (templates) the Sort will become a template, too.

Answer (score 1):

You need a template.

There is absolutely no relationship between a `std::vector<Base>` and a `std::vector<Derived>`, nor between a `std::vector<Base*>` and a `std::vector<Derived*>`, nor any other wrapper. The language will not allow you to substitute these things without an unsafe typecast, which is just undefined behavior.

If you have a function that takes a `std::vector<Base%>` (substitute `%` by whatever), then that's what you need to pass. The only way to do that is to create a new vector of the correct type and fill it.

Or you make it so that the function is more flexible, and that's by making it a template.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to operate on the container's elements (e.g. sort them), I would suggest that you follow the convention that people would expect:  that is, the pattern used in the standard library.

```
template<typename RandomAccessIterator>
void foo(RandomAccessIterator start, RandomAccessIterator end) { ... }
```

This way you make it easy to use for either of your classes (`Base` or `Derived`), and anyone else looking at your code should easily be able to tell what it is doing.

If you are attempting to sort, you can also provide a `Predicate` version of the template that allows you to provide a sorting method that is different from your default (e.g. if you want to sort largest to smallest).